# Parking in the open in heavy rains

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, environment

What if my bike is left 4-5 hours during heavy rains 5 days a week for 12 weeks?
This type of weather is common in India during monsoon. I drive to work where there is open parking leaving my bike unprotected from rains.

What should I do? Is it harmful for the bike?

Comment: Are you talking about a bicycle or a motorbike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about a motorcycle, i would recomend you to invest in a motorcycle cover that you could pull over your bike when it's parked.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of scenario is not good for any automobile.

Especially when you include "Monsoon".

Since you will be driving it everyday your only real problem will be way of dealing with rust.

Use WD - 40 (will cost you around INR 300) to combat corrosion.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Plz elaborate WD40, I guess its for bicycles. A simple spray can protecf my chain? Anything else i need to do about other bike parts?

Comment: @ashutosh Just for bicycles? ROFL its used on 18wheeler trucks , its not a simple spray trust me, its a motorhead's secret. People are religious about it in the motorworld.